# want to connect multiple users with MySql server?

Tags: mysql

can i connect multiple users with a user name and password on a single port  with Mysql server

if not then what is the best approach to do this

help required

regards.

Comment: what do you mean? Do you want to access the server from a program which is ran many times and uses the same user?

Comment: yea a program the runs on 2 or 3 different machines and access DB with same user

Comment: have you already tried it and it failed?

Comment: have implemented it but not test it just wana sure it will not be a big mistake i don't want to write any server side service to handle this just want to leave this work on mysql server i think it is possible. if there is any thing that can make this wrong please tell me about this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work fine. It is the normal usecase of a SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how your Server is set up. If you chose to let two people share the same creedentials consequently they will be able to both access certain data.

Comment: Just create a table in your query on the server with two identical usernames, being able to access the same txt string or whatever you want them to share. Be aware to not include any code prohibiting users to create unique users though, then you're server settings will be useless.